# ArbotiX-M Problem uploading to the board

Tags: avrdude, mac-os

I have an ArbotiX-m Arduino board, and have followed the [setup guide](http://learn.trossenrobotics.com/arbotix/7-arbotix-quick-start-guide) on Trossen robotics all the way to the 5th step. I have a Mac running OS X 10.10 and use Arduino 1.0.5. I installed the necessary drivers and copied the files to the Sketchbook directory. When I try to load the sample ArbotiXBlink program:

```
// Pin 0 maps to the USER LED on the ArbotiX Robocontroller.
int led = 0;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
}
```

It verifies just fine, but when I click upload, I get:

```
Binary sketch size: 1,088 bytes (of a 65,536 byte maximum)
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** The board was trying to get power from the 5V instead of USB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured why my board wasn't responding! Apparently, the power pin was connected to the 5V supply instead of usb. Silly me!

Comment: Please add it as an edit.

Comment: No, this is proper as answers are the vehicle for solutions (even when they come from the asker), while question edits are the means of adding additional detail about the problem.